# Finding an orthogonal basis for the given symmetric bilinear form.

Tags: symmetric-matrices, bilinear-form

Consider the symmetric bilinear form $f(x,y)=x_1y_1+5x_2y_2+x_3y_3+2x_1y_2+2x_2y_1+3x_1y_3+3x_3y_1$.I am asked to find an orthogonal basis for this symmetric bilinear form.Hence,I am asked to find a matrix $P$ such that $P^tAP$ is diagonal,where $A=\begin{pmatrix}1 &2&3\\2& 5&0\\3&0&1\end{pmatrix}$.I have done this problem and I want to know whether it is correct or not.

$f(x,x)=x_1^2+5x_2^2+x_3^2+4x_1x_2+6x_1x_3$ .We observe that for $x=(1,0,0)$ ,$f(x,x)=1\neq 0$.So we take $\alpha_1=(1,0,0)$,Now we calculate the orthogonal complement of $W=\{\alpha_1\}$ which is $\{(x_1,x_2,x_3)\in \mathbb R^3: x_1+2x_2+3x_3=0\}$.We take a vector from this orthogonal complement viz. $\alpha_2=(2,-1,0)$.We now find vector orthogonal to both $\alpha_1$ and $\alpha_2$ which is a solution of $x_1+2x_2+3x_3=0$ and $-x_2+6x_3=0$.We find a vector $(-15,6,1)$ satisfying the $2$ equations.Take it as $\alpha_3$.Now by constrution,$\{
\alpha_1,\alpha_2,\alpha_3\}$ is an orthogonal basis.Now the matrix $P$ that would make $A$ into diagonal matrix is $P=\begin{pmatrix}1 & 2 & -15\\0 & -1 & 6\\0 & 0 &1\end{pmatrix}$.Is my solution correct?

Comment: it is unlikely that they are asking for $P$   to be orthogonal. That would require knowing the eigenvalues, while the characteristic polynomial $x^3 -7x^2  -2x+44$  has three real irrational roots, there is no good way to deal with them by hand. See http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1388421/reference-for-linear-algebra-books-that-teach-reverse-hermite-method-for-symmetr  for "completing the square"

Comment: They are not asking for $P$ to be orthogonal.

Comment: using variables $x,y,z$  the bilinear form becomes quadratic form $x^2 +5y^2 + z^2  + 6 zx + 4 xy  ..   $   Your are trying to write this as a sum with coefficients; I would begin with $(x+2y+3z)^2, $  continue  $(x+2y+3z)^2  + a(by + cz)^2 + d z^2 $  Anyway, the rows of $Q$  in $Q^T D Q = A$  are $(1,2,3),$   $(0,b,c),$   third $(0,0,1)$  while the diagonal elements of $D$  are $1,a,d$

Comment: yours works; I got 
$$\left( 
\begin{array}{rrr} 
1 & 0 & 0 \\ 
2 & 1 & 0 \\ 
3 &  - 6 & 1 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
\left( 
\begin{array}{rrr} 
1 & 0 & 0 \\ 
0 & 1 & 0 \\ 
0 & 0 &  - 44 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
\left( 
\begin{array}{rrr} 
1 & 2 & 3 \\ 
0 & 1 &  - 6 \\ 
0 & 0 & 1 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
 = \left( 
\begin{array}{rrr} 
1 & 2 & 3 \\ 
2 & 5 & 0 \\ 
3 & 0 & 1 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
$$